# DefaultAzureCredential error on macOS Big Sur (M1 chip)

Tags: azure, macos, azure-managed-identity, defaultazurecredential

Currently, we are migrating our Azure resources to communicate via Azure System Managed Identity. I encountered an issue using DefaultAzureCredential on my MacOS with M1 chip.

As I understand Visual Studio for Mac is not supporting DefaultAzureCredential, but I installed Azure CLI and log in using CLI, but DefaultAzureCredential is not recognizing it either.

Does anyone aware is this supported on MacOS or this is my configuration issue?

> DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. [https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot\n-](https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot%5Cn-) EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. [https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot\n-](https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot%5Cn-) ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.\n- Operating system Darwin 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Mon Aug 30 06:12:20 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.6~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 isn't supported.\n- Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. [https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot\n-](https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/vscodecredential/troubleshoot%5Cn-) Azure CLI not installed\n- Az.Account module >= 2.2.0 is not installed.

Comment: What’s the version of Azure CLI installed on your Mac?

Comment: azure-cli is in 2.29 version